Multiple Sheets with Proc Report
I am having some trouble using ODS Excel with Proc Report. For some reason - I cannot successfully create one excel file with multiple sheets using Proc Report. The first sheet holds multiple tables, and runs fine by itself. Once I try to add a new sheet, it gives an error that the options statement is unrecognized.
ods excel file="C:\Users\me\desktop\_Draft_&stamp..xlsx"
options (embedded_titles='ON' sheet_interval='NONE' sheet_name='First Tab')
; 
Title j=left height=16pt 'Title1';
proc report data=set1;
run;
Title j=left height=16pt 'Title2';
proc report data=set2;
run;
Title j=left height=16pt 'Title3';
proc report data=set3;
run;

ods excel options (embedded_titles='ON' sheet_name='Second Tab');
Title j=center height=16pt 'Title4';
proc report data=set4 nowd;
  column Year Qtr ('Category1' va1 var2 var3) 
                  ('Category2' va4 var5 var6);
  define Year / display;
  define Quarter / display;
  define var1 / display;
  define var2 / display;
  define var3 / display;
  define var4 / display;
  define var5 / display;
  define var6 / display;
run;
ods excel close;

I have not been able to solve this issue even after research, and shifting around option statements.

Your first statement (ods excel...) defines a couple of ODS options, in particular this: sheet_interval='NONE'
The sheet_interval option controls how ODS engine outputs reports in your document:

TABLE (the default value) - new sheet for each table in output
NONE - keep the output that follows on the current sheet
PAGE - new sheet for each page of SAS output
PROC - new sheet beginning at the PROC step boundary
BYGROUP - new sheet for each BY group of output
NOW - begin a new sheet immediately

In your sample, you explicitly asked to your ODS engine to not create new sheet. So, despite you provided a new sheet name for your 2nd proc report, it's not created because the sheet_interval = 'NONE' option is still applicable
The solution is to change the value of that option when you define a new sheet, like this:
ods excel file="C:\Users\me\desktop\_Draft_&stamp..xlsx"
options (embedded_titles='ON' sheet_interval='NONE' sheet_name='First Tab')
;

*-- Define here all the proc reports to output in the 1st sheet --*;
proc report
...
run;

proc report
...
run;

*-- Define a new sheet, ensuring with sheet_interval that ODS output will target the new sheet --*;
ods excel options (embedded_titles='ON' sheet_interval='NOW' sheet_name='Second Tab');

proc report
...
run;

ods excel close;


As stated - The sheet interval option is needed for the first sheet since I have multiple tables going to one sheet. The second sheet is the issue. When the "sheet_interval" option is removed in the second options statement, the 4th table goes on the first sheet. I need the 4th table created on its own sheet.

Well, apologizes, I updated the answer to fit your needs

Bingo! Thank you! Wonder why I couldn't figure this out... time to hang it up I think LOL. Thank-you, sir. Check Mark for you.

Don't you need to redefine the sheet_interval at the point you want a new sheet.
ods excel options (embedded_titles='ON' sheet_interval='NOW' sheet_name='Second Tab');

